# Как сделать чтобы контент подгружался только после нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Как переделать код, чтобы контент подгружался только после нажатия кнопки? Сейчас контент загружается независимо от нажатия, после нажатия он просто уже показывается. Заранее спасибо с уважением.
Код кнопки:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#demo").on("hide.bs.collapse", function() {
    $(".btn").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Показать');
  });
  $("#demo").on("show.bs.collapse", function() {
    $(".btn").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up"></span> Закрыть');
  });
});
```

```css
.tp-sbscr-widget-alert {
  display: none!important;
}
.glyphicon,
.glyphicon-star {
  color: #f5a626 !important;
}
body {
  font: 400 15px Lato, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #818181;
}
p {
  margin: 10px 10px 10px!important;
}
.btn,
.btn1,
.btn2,
.btn3,
.btn4,
.btn-info:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #31b0d5;
  border-color: #269abc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #303030;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  color: #303030;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.logo {
  color: #f4511e;
  font-size: 200px;
}
.thumbnail {
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.thumbnail img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.carousel-control.right,
.carousel-control.left {
  background-image: none;
  color: #f4511e;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  border-color: #f4511e;
}
.carousel-indicators li.active {
  background-color: #f4511e;
}
.item h4 {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 70px 0;
}
.item span {
  font-style: normal;
}
.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fdd835!important;
  border-color: #ddd;
}
.panel-footer {
  background-color: white !important;
}
.panel-footer h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
}
.panel-footer h4 {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.panel-footer .btn {
  margin: 15px 0;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(51, 122, 183, 0.88) url(/image/bluefon.png)!important;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.navbar li a,
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff !important;
}
.navbar-nav li a:hover,
.navbar-nav li.active a {
  color: #f4511e !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff !important;
}
footer .glyphicon {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #f4511e;
}
table,
td {
  color: #777777;
}
.slideanim {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.slide {
  animation-name: slide;
  -webkit-animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  visibility: visible;
}
.bs-wizard {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #e0e0e0;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step + .bs-wizard-step {} .bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step .bs-wizard-stepnum {
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step .bs-wizard-info {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step > .bs-wizard-dot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  background: #fbe8aa;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step > .bs-wizard-dot:after {
  content: ' ';
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: #fbbd19;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step > .progress {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 8px;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: #fbe8aa !important;
}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step > .progress > .bar {
  width: 0px;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: #fbe8aa!important;
}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step.complete > .progress > .bar {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fbe8aa !important;
}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step.active > .progress > .bar {
  width: 50%;
  background: #fbe8aa !important;
}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step:first-child.active > .progress > .bar {
  width: 100%;
}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step:last-child.active > .progress > .bar {
  width: 100%;
}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step.disabled > .bs-wizard-dot {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step.disabled > .bs-wizard-dot:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step:first-child > .progress {
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step:last-child > .progress {
  width: 50%;
}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step.disabled a.bs-wizard-dot {
  pointer-events: none;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-4 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 25px 0;
  }
  .btn-lg {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
  }
  .mob {
    display: none!important;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .logo {
    font-size: 150px;
  }
  .mob {
    display: none!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script async="async" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="padding:0px; margin:0px auto;text-align:center;">
  <h2>Больше авиабилетов<br>из Москвы в Адлер</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Показать</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      КОНТЕНТ
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ajax вам в помощь

Comment: Да, я неправильно сформулировал вопрос. Как переделать код? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Переделайте его так, чтобы контент грузился через ajax. Если не знаете как, на фрилансе вам помогут.

Comment: У меня сайт без базы данных на чистом html+php

Comment: @Arcadiy как то не понятно обяснили какой контент должен быть виден  после нажатия кнопки?

Comment: вот сайт поиска дешевых авиабилетов, взято отсюда https://avia-avia.ru

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать при помощи AJAX. Код который вы привели не объясняет чего вы собственно хотите подгружать. И ещё от себя добавлю, если речь идёт о подгрузке небольшого абзаца текста, то лучше не делать никаких AJAX запросов.

Comment: Вот какой объем информации мне нужно подгружать. http://avia-avia.ru/#kurorty там ниже кнопка нажмите на нее. И таких кнопок будет много, сервер уже не справляется из-за этого загрузка сайта замедляется

Comment: @Arcadiy AJAX тут не поможет существенно уменьшить вес страницы, тут дизайнера надо звать. А вообще такая подгрузка нужна для чего то тяжелого, например для больших картинок. Лишний запрос это всё равно задержка, т.е. выпадающий список не будет так моментально раскрываться, а будет подвисать.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Вот эта штучка загружает данные сразу, как только загрузится страница. Чтобы подгружать данные по нажатию на кнопку, нужно что-то типа:

```
$("#id кнопки").on("click", function(){
//Код загрузки данных
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть как-то так?
По клику на кнопу - запрос к апи, приходящий ответ выводится через js

```js
(function () {
    // "глобальные" переменные
    let total = document.querySelector('.result'),
        button = document.querySelector('.search-btn'),
        forAll = {};
    
    // функции
    async function getData() {
        let getData = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
        let data = await getData.json();
        forAll.data = data;
        for( let currentValue of data){
            let createdDiv = document.createElement("div");
            createdDiv.innerHTML = `<p>${currentValue.id}` +`. ` + ` ${currentValue.title}</p>`
            total.appendChild(createdDiv, total)
        }
    }

    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        getData()
    })

})();
```

```css
.search{
    margin: 15px auto 0;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #eee;
    max-width: 400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.search-input{
      background-color: #fff;
      border: none;
      min-height: 40px;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 350px;
      border-radius: 15px;
      padding: 5px 15px;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 14px;
      font-weight: 600;
      outline: none;
}
.search-btn{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 150px;
    min-height: 40px;
    background: orange;
    border: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 15px auto 0;
}
p{
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.result{
    margin: 15px auto 35px;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #eee;
    max-width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <button class="search-btn">кнопка</button>
</div>
<div class="result"><b>Результат:</b></div>
```

Оу, не увидел, что прошло пять лет)